# Why infinitesimal generator of the autonomous differential equation $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=\textbf{b}(x(t))$ is gradient operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, operator-algebras

> Let $\mathscr{X}=C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}), b\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$, consider $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=\textbf{b}(x(t)),$$ where $x(0)=\xi$ is a autonomous differential equation.
>
> For $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n $, $\exists x(t,\xi)$, $0\leq t<\infty$, s.t. $x(t)\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^1,\mathbb{R}^n)$. Define operator
> $$T(t): f(\xi) \rightarrow f(x(t,\xi)).$$

My questions:

1. what does $f$ mean? I try to show $T(t)T(s)=T(s+t)$, but $(T(s+t)f)(\xi)=f(x(s+t,\xi))=?$
2. How to prove: if $A$ is the infinitesimal generator, then $C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^1)\subset D(A).$ And as $f \in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^1)$,
   $$ (Af)(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n b^{i}(x)\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_{i}},$$
   where $\textbf{b}(x)=(b^{1}(x),..,b^{n}(x))$.

Comment: 1: It is a basic property of flows generated by a (complete) $C^1$ vector field that $x(t+s,\xi)=x(t,x(s,\xi))$ for any $t,s\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Apply the function $f$ to both sides of the equality. Incidentally, what is $C^1_o$?

Comment: @user539887 Do you mean $\frac{df(x(t))}{dt}=\textbf{b}(f(x(t)))$? Why $x(t+s, \xi)=x(t, x(s,\xi))$? And $C_{0}^1$ is a notation same as $C_{c}^1$.

Comment: Answer to the first question: No.  Answer to the second question: Please check any textbook on how the autonomous ODE gives rise to a dynamical system.  Answer to the third question: What is $C^1_c$?  The space of $C^1$ functions with compact support?

Comment: @user539887 : It depends on the definitions. $C^1_0$ may be the functions that are zero at infinity, while $C^1_c$ functions with compact support (which obviously are also zero at infinity).

Comment: @LutzL Yes, I know that.  And that's why I keep asking the OP what definition he/she has in mind.

Comment: @user539887 Sorry, I am not familiar with the autonomous ODE gives rise to a dynamical system. Could you tell me a textbook including this content?

Comment: @user539887 Yup! As the explanation of $C_{c}^{1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule you get $$\frac{df(x(t))}{dt}=f'(x(t))\dot x(t)=f'(x(t))b(x(t)),$$ and if you transpose that, you get $$\frac{df(x(t))}{dt}=b(x(t))^Tf'(x(t))^T=b(x(t))^T\nabla f(x(t)).$$

---

By the way, your notation does not make sense. $f(ξ)$ is a function value, a point, or a real number in this case. What you can to is define
$$
T(t):C^1(R^n,R)\to C^1(R^n,R),~~ [T(t)(f)](ξ)=f(x(t;ξ))
$$

Comment: If $f$ in a functional space? Does it make sense?

Comment: I mean the $f$ left the base space of $x$?

Comment: Yes, $C^1(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$ is a functional space and $f$ here is an element of it.

Answer (score 0):

Because I am too lazy to look in the literature for a proof of the group property, and because it is, however, much too long for a comment, I am giving it here as an answer.

Assume that the $C^1$ vector field $\mathbf{b}$ is *forward complete*:  For every $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the domain of the (necessarily) unique nonextendible solution of the IVP 
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = \mathbf{b}(x(t))
\\[0.5em]
x(0) = \xi
\end{cases}
$$
contains $[0, \infty)$.  Denote such a solution by $\varphi(\cdot, \xi)$.

We want to show that 
$$
\tag{$*$}
\varphi(t+s,\xi) = \varphi(t, \varphi(s, \xi)) \quad \text{ for all }s, t \ge 0, \ \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
Fix $s \ge 0$ and $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Consider the mapping
$$
[0, \infty) \ni t \mapsto \varphi(t+s,\xi) \in \mathbb{R}^n,
$$ 
as well as the mapping
$$
[0, \infty) \ni t \mapsto \varphi(t, \varphi(s, \xi)) \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
They both satisfy the IVP
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = \mathbf{b}(x(t))
\\[0.5em]
x(0) = \varphi(s, \xi).
\end{cases}
$$
By uniqueness, they must be the same mapping, which concludes the proof of $(*)$.

Now, for *any* (even not necessarily continuous) function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^1$ the property
$$
T(t) (T(s) f) = T(t + s) f \quad \text{ for all }s, t \ge 0
$$
follows directly from $(*)$.

Comment: Do you mean $x(t)=\varphi(t,\xi)$?

Comment: Yes. I would like to lay stress on the fact that in an equation, $x$ is a "generic" value, whereas when we consider the solution, it is fixed (look at the second IVP).